# Joda time and ProGuard error when exporting .apk

Tags: java, android, proguard, jodatime

In Eclipse when I export my .apk and enable proguard I'm getting the following build errors:

```
[2014-07-10 04:13:30 - VirginMobile] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-07-10 04:13:30 - VirginMobile] Warning: org.joda.convert.JDKStringConverter$9: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
[2014-07-10 04:13:30 - VirginMobile] Warning: org.joda.convert.JDKStringConverter$9: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
[2014-07-10 04:13:30 - VirginMobile] Warning: org.joda.convert.JDKStringConverter$9: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
[2014-07-10 04:13:30 - VirginMobile]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2014-07-10 04:13:30 - VirginMobile] Warning: there were 3 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2014-07-10 04:13:30 - VirginMobile]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2014-07-10 04:13:30 - VirginMobile] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2014-07-10 04:13:30 - VirginMobile]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2014-07-10 04:13:30 - VirginMobile]    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2014-07-10 04:13:30 - VirginMobile]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2014-07-10 04:13:30 - VirginMobile]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Couldn't find a solution in any other threads.

I included both joda-time-2.3.jar and joda-convert-1.6.jar (which took away all but three errors).  Anyone know how to fix this?

Much appreciation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Joda class `org.joda.convert.JDKStringConverter` makes use of the Java API class `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`, which is not available in the Android API.

Joda may still work on Android if you don't actually use the JDKStringConverter class, but ProGuard tries to ensure that all dependencies are fulfilled.

You could try to tell ProGuard to ignore the missing dependency with the option "-dontwarn javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter".

Comment: This is the closest thing to an answer I have found.  While it didn't completely work for me (there were still two errors after compiling), simply ignoring the rest of the errors seemed to do the trick.  I ended up just scrapping Joda completely, but that's beside the point.